# React useState change in array of objects not causing a render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I'm currently learning react and i've ran into a problem I cannot seem to find a solution for. I'm calling a backend api to get an array of todos and store using useState.

```js
const [todoListState, setTodoListState] = useState<TodoType[]>(todos)
```

I'm then looping through the array to create a component for each todo

```js
{todoListState.map((todo) => 
   <Todo key={todo.id} handelDel={handleDeleteButton} handleEdit={handleEditButton} todo={todo}/>
)}
```

In my edit function I have tried several different ways to update the state however none of them have worked. I either end up duplicating the component or in this case, the component gets updated, but fails to re-render.

```js
    setTodoListState((prev) => ([
      ...prev.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          return editedTodo
        } else {
          return todo
        }
      }) 
    ]))
```

Object fails to rerender

```js
    setTodoListState(prev => ([
      ...prev,
      editedTodo
    ]))
```

Object gets duplicated

Is there a solution for this problem or should I rethink how I am managing state here? I know the issue comes down to the fact that I'm updating an object inside of an array so react doesn't see the change. I've considered managing state in the child component to avoid the 'shallow compare'. Is that typically how you solve this issue or is there a better way?

Comment: If you do a setState, react will rerender, there's nothing wrong with an object inside of an array, something else must be off. Can you provide a bit more code ?

Comment: I think the issue is that only the object inside the array gets updated. So because the array itself does not change, React does not rerender the component. I changed it so each todo component has it's own state and it works.

Comment: It's probably better that each todo component manages its own state if you don't need in the parent. However, it seems very weird that your previous case wouldn't work.